# How to add a link to the rest of the paragraph in SharePoint Announcements?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

How can I create a link to the rest of the paragraph in an announcement in SharePoint, that displays the word: **read more**

Cheers

Comment: @Nassi - did my answer help, or did you require something else?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the cleanest, easiest way to do this is to create a template in ItemStyle.xsl which selects a substring of the body content of the announcement and displays a link below to the article itself.

After adding the following code to your ItemStyle.xsl file (in SharePoint Designer navigate to the 'Style Library/XSL Style Sheets' folder), you can modify the web part through the browser, and change the Item Style (Presentation/Styles) to 'ReadMoreAnnouncements'. This code keeps the amount of characters displayed to 190 characters (see the substring($bodyContent,1,190 function call).

```
<xsl:template name="removeMarkup">
       <xsl:param name="string" />
       <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="contains($string, '&lt;')">
              <xsl:variable name="nextString">
                     <xsl:call-template name="removeMarkup">
                     <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, '&gt;')" />
                     </xsl:call-template>
              </xsl:variable>
              <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($string, '&lt;'), $nextString)" />
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="$string" />
       </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template> 
<xsl:template name="ReadMoreAnnouncements" match="Row[@Style='ReadMoreAnnouncements']" mode="itemstyle">
    <br />
    <div class="RMAnnouncementsTitle">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Title" />
    </div>
    <div class="RMAnnouncementsBody">
        <xsl:variable name="bodyContent">
            <xsl:call-template name="removeMarkup">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="@Body"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($bodyContent,1,190)" />
        ...
        <br />
        <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                /Lists/Announcements/DispForm.aspx?ID=
                <xsl:value-of select="@ID">
                </xsl:value-of>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                RMAnnouncementsMoreLink
            </xsl:attribute>
            read more
        </a>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

This should definitely work, and it's very very easy to implement.

Comment: Ryan,
I know I'm soo late answering you but yes, thanks, just checked again this website and I'm trying to implement it.
I opened in SharePoint designer the ItemStyle.xsl and checked it out then tried to add your code but it doesn't paste it?!
Have I missed an other step? I'm new at Sharepoint designer and I am very careful with it. Many thanks again!
Nassi

Answer (score 0):

If you have a page and can edit it in SharePoint Designer, try [this](http://randomdust.com/blogs/ryan/archive/2007/09/27/customize-announcements-summary-view.aspx).
If you want to have a web part that shows the announcement the way you want, try [this](http://philwicklund.com/archive/2008/05/02/enhancement-to-the-announcements-list-view-web-part.aspx).